# What is expected behaviour from Server returning Http 416

Tags: http-headers

I have a server and sometimes when client ask for a file and if its request header Range may get over the length of file, so the server returns 416 status code. But I'm wondering should it write file content too ? or simply return 416 with no content ?

Explaination on [W3 Website](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) doesn't clearify enough.

What I understood from the W3 web, that it should write Content-Range header(starting with 0?).
So if content length is 10 bytes. The response should look like

```
HTTP/1.1 416
Content-Range: bytes 0-9/10
Content-Length: 10    

[10 bytes FILE CONTENT HERE]
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be serving a 206 in this case.

[RFC 7233](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233) makes it clear that if *any part* of the requested range is satisfiable then that is what you send back, even if part of the range is not satisfiable.

From section 2.1:

> If a valid byte-range-set includes at least one byte-range-spec with a first-byte-pos that is less than the current length of the representation, or at least one suffix-byte-range-spec with a non-zero suffix-length, then the byte-range-set is satisfiable. Otherwise, the byte-range-set is unsatisfiable.

So if your file is 1000 bytes, and the client requests bytes=501-2000, you will return a 206 and serve bytes 501-1000. (And remember that ranges start from zero, so watch out for off-by-one errors.)

In the case where *no* part of the range is satisfiable, you send a 416 error, but you do not send any file content. The whole point of the error is that there is nothing to send!

Comment: no no, thats not what I asked. I meant what if client asked 2000-4000 while file is only 1000 bytes. So server will return 416, but question is, should server write content too ?

Comment: No, you don't send any content in that case.